# Can't upload public PGP/GPG key to OpenSKS server

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird, ubuntu-18.04, enigmail

So I have an Intranet that won't be connected to the Internet when in use, and one of the functionalities I need is the ability to send and receive encrypted emails.
I chose to use an OpenSKS server for easier exchange of public keys, which i run on Ubuntu 18.04. I set it up using the following commands I found online:

```
sudo apt-get install sks
sudo sks build
sudo chown -Rc debian-sks:debian-sks /var/lib/sks/DB
sudo /etc/init.d/sks start
```

After that the system tells me:

```
[ ok ] Starting sks (via systemctl): sks.service.
```

So I assume that it's properly set up.

The clients that'll be connected to the network run Win10 Home and use ThunderBird with the Enigmail extension. During Setup, I put in the IP of the OpenSKS server and tried uploading my key to it. After that didn't work I added a AAAA-entry for this server on my WinServer which functions as the DNS-server on my network so that i could enter "keys.local" as the server address in Thunderbird/Enigmail. I thought this would solve my problem because every tutorial I found online also had a proper URL for the keyserver instead of its IP-address.

But that didn't change anything, I still get an error telling me the upload failed.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem and has a solution for this, I'd be very grateful. I hope I provided all of the needed information about my situation, if not, just tell me and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: Does the SKS server have any logfiles in /var/log, or messages in `journalctl -b`? Also, CNAME entry to what? CNAMEs point to an existing name. If all you had was an IP address, you needed an A/AAAA record.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to write AAAA, my bad. Still pretty early around here. Using journalctl -b, it tells me about 20 times "ubuntu sks[1811]: 2019-01-07 00:58:05 <recon as client> error in callback.: Failure("No gossip partners available")"

Comment: Finally, are you able to connect to the keyserver through a web browser (via `http://keys.local:11371`)?

Comment: I can't connect to the server on port 11371, however I'm able to reach the regular apache default page I set up on the server because i was also planning on offering a webinterface to upload keys

Comment: Apache is not relevant; if you can't connect to SKS _directly_, figure out why it isn't running. (It has a barebones web-ui built in.)

Comment: But that's why I posted this question in the first place, I have no idea why it isn't running and I'm too unexperienced using linux to assess why